# delphi blowfish mode ecb (python converter to delphi)

Tags: delphi, blowfish

I know as a programmer that is rare for someone to do, but I actually need it and can not at all so someone needs to convert this small function cryptography python for delphi.

```
function: `
from Crypto.Cipher import Blowfish   

class Blowfish(object):   
    cipher = None   

    def __init__(self, key, mode = Blowfish.MODE_ECB):   
        self.cipher = Blowfish.new(key, mode)   

    def encrypt(self, texto):   
        encriptar = self.cipher.encrypt(texto)   
        return encriptar `
```

-

```
one example
key = 123key
text = hi man
result = ìûÕ]–•¢
```

I people much times because I tried to do in Delphi and always shows me different results then do better and ask for someone who understands python / delphi

thank so much!

Answer (score 1):

For the comment on DCPcrypt, maybe your python library results the raw encrypted bytes, and the result of DCPcrypt (or other delphi library like Turbo Lockbox) gives you the result encoded in something like UU64 o MIME (this is done to easily transfer o store the result)

Comment: like http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/ same criptor but show results diferences :S.. in python have other function  "padData" decrypting

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to implement Blowfish algorithm in Delphi, try [DCPcrypt](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/cryptography.html).

Comment: i tried DCPcrypt but evertime result diferences 
correctly is key = 123key text = hi man result = ìûÕ]–•¢
but in DCP_crypt is key = 123key text = hi man result = kKPLZV=

Comment: DCPCrypt returns the result in base64 encoding. The hex representation of the result is: 90A3CB6550. Don't try to use the result as a string: it's not and you're not going to get anything interesting out of it.

Comment: how i can then ?, u have a example for me ?

Comment: i tryied it var sTmp,IV,Key : String; begin Key := PadWithZeros('123key',32); IV := PadWithZeros('',16); DCP_blowfish1.Init(Key[1],192,@IV[1]); sTmp := PadWithZeros(Edit1.Text,16); DCP_blowfish1.EncryptECB(sTmp[1],sTmp[1]); Edit2.text := base64encode(stmp); memo1.lines.Add( 'Blowfish: '+stmp); memo1.lines.Add('BASE64encode: '+base64encode(stmp)); DCP_blowfish1.Burn; result of "hi man" is ¸ú"»Ì/Îb but in python and MMF is ìûÕ]–•¢ DAMN!! =/

Answer (score 0):

@Mili, you can't translate this code to delphi because does not exist a RTL library (or function) in delphi with blowfish support, dou you need use a third party component for this. i recommend you the 
[Delphi Encryption Compedium Part I v.5.2](http://www.torry.net/vcl/security/strong/DECv5.2.zip). you can try out this [link](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=519) for more components.

Comment: same problem..  is result diferences =/

Comment: @Mili, try using these test vectors to see wich implementation is wrong http://www.schneier.com/code/vectors.txt

Comment: idk.. i only can in multimedia fusion (DecryptString('BLOWFISH object'),'key','text') and python but in delphi i not search a correctly function

Comment: i tryied it var
  sTmp,IV,Key : String;
begin
  Key := PadWithZeros('123key',32);
  IV := PadWithZeros('',16);
  DCP_blowfish1.Init(Key[1],192,@IV[1]);
  sTmp := PadWithZeros(Edit1.Text,16);
  DCP_blowfish1.EncryptECB(sTmp[1],sTmp[1]);
  Edit2.text := base64encode(stmp);
   memo1.lines.Add( 'Blowfish: '+stmp);
  memo1.lines.Add('BASE64encode: '+base64encode(stmp));

  DCP_blowfish1.Burn;  result of "hi man" is ¸ú"»Ì/Îb  but in python and MMF is  ìûÕ]–•¢   DAMN!! =/

Answer (score 0):

You can also try TurboPower LockBox 3.1.0 at http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/ .
This library also implements Blowfish.